# How disabled dark mode in tailwind css

Tags: laravel-8, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, darkmode

I'm using the package laravel livewire table ([laravel livewire table][1]

[1]: https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables) on my laravel app (v8).

I also use tailwind CSS on v3.

By default this package add some tailwind class for dark mode on tables. But I don't want to use dark mode. I want my site to stay light whatever the browser configuration.

I read that I have to set it on tailwind.config.js so I try some things like :

```js
module.exports = {

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
    darkMode: false,
};
```

```js
module.exports = {

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
    darkMode: 'class',
};
```

```js
module.exports = {

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
    darkMode: 'media',
};
```

No one works for disabling dark mode...

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables package uses `dark` mode in itself, so it is configured to work that way.

The thing you can do is to always force `light` mode by doing something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  // ...
}
```

And then in header of your page, you can have this small script that will override everything and just use `light` mode.

```js
localStorage.theme = 'light'
```

Resource: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#supporting-system-preference-and-manual-selection

Answer (score 14):

changes

```
darkMode: false,
```

to

```
darkMode: 'false',
```

its work for me

Comment: where?!! file name please

Comment: tailwind.config.js

Comment: When Typescript is employed in the project, it will not like it.

Answer (score 0):

This will enforce light mode does not matter OS settings or extensions:

```
@layer base {
  html {
    color-scheme: light !important;
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that many UI kits will ignore it, so it is useable only when you use Tailwind only.